# Вывести значение на окно

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, переменные

надо вывести полученное значение в окно. можно ли в xaml передать переменную для Text:

```
<TextBox Name="Length_txt" Width="150" Height="24"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
         Margin="10"
         Grid.Row="1"
         Text="{Binding Answers}" <<!--нет контекста-->
         BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"/>

    public MainWindow(){
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Answerlist();
    }

public class Answerlist{
    private static string[] answers = File.ReadAllLines("res/latin.txt");

    public static string Answers { get; set; } = $"{answers.Length}";

    public static string getRandomAnswer(){
        return answers[new Random().Next(answers.Length)];
    }
}
```

ошибки нет и прога фунтициклирует, но значение не выводится...

Comment: `DataContext = new MainViewModel();` в конструкторе окна (название зависит от типа проекта), далее делаете класс `public class MainViewModel { public string Text {get;set;} = "Привет мир!"; }`, ну и остается в XAML написать `{Binding Text}`. Все, вот у вас переменная, которая задает текст. Добро пожаловать в мир привязок как говорится) Единственно, если будете менять при запущенном приложении, то нужен еще `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Ну а если "тупо" хотите, невзирая на все рекомендации и прочее, то просто `Length_txt.Text = "Привет мир!";` Но потом не удивляйтесь каше в проекте.

Comment: Вопрос из разряда "не умею искать примитивную информацию, помогите!". Да без проблем, я поискал: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/11.php

Comment: EvgeniyZ - не очень понятно "в конструкторе окна" какого окна. aepot - инфу принял к изучению.

Comment: вопрос отредактировал в свете новой информации

Comment: Почему у меня тогда все [выводится](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFlx9.png)? Прям взял ваш код, всунул в чистый проект, получил нужный результат.  И да, отучайтесь от статики, она зло. Если у вас в проекте везде статика, то значит что-то пошло не так. Ну и да, зачем вам два свойства? Сделали одно `public string[] Answers { get; set; } = File.ReadAllLines("res/latin.txt");`, а дальше с ним работайте везде, где надо, включая привязки `Text="{Binding Answers.Length, Mode=OneWay}"` (`OneWay` потому, что свойство длины не имеет `set`, из-за чего мы не можем ему задать значение, включая привязку).

Comment: EvgeniyZ - спасибо всё получилось. по поводу статики - убрал и создал объект в основном классе. вроде всё фунтициклирует. тему можно закрыть.